# INFO: Additional JARs have been added : 'xalan-2.7.0.jar'

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven-2

After a successful start of Tomcat and a few REST calls I get this message in Tomcat console and then the application reload it self. And because reload takes a few seconds, response time is too long. And then again - after a REST call I again get this message and it reloads the application again...

Google did not help me, can you? :)

My (long) pom.xml:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>core</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Core</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>terracotta-repository</id>
            <name>Terracotta</name>
            <url>http://www.terracotta.org/download/reflector/maven2</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- this profile is for deploying to jboss as -->
            <id>jboss</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6.SEC01</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Struts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-rest-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-spring-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Terracotta -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.terracotta.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>tim-distributed-cache</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JiBX -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-run</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
            <artifactId>jibx-extras</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Axis -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- provided by tomcat -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>httpcomponents-httpcore</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta-httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-alpha2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-attributes</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-attributes-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>quartz</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>8.4-701.jdbc3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate & JPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.8</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>core</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!--
                        <plugin>
                            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                            <configuration>
                                <descriptorRefs>
                                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                </descriptorRefs>
                                <archive>
                                    <manifest>
                                        <mainClass></mainClass>
                                    </manifest>
                                </archive>
                            </configuration>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>attached</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
            -->

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-idea-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <dependenciesAsLibraries>true</dependenciesAsLibraries>
                    <useFullNames>false</useFullNames>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jibx</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jibx-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <directory>src/main/resources/config/rest/mappings</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>*.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                    <!--<verbose>true</verbose>-->
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>bind</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--  -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                                <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                <property name="test_classpath" refid="maven.test.classpath"/>
                                <property name="plugin_classpath" refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>

                                <fileset id="dataClasses" dir="${basedir}/src/main/java" includes="**/*.java">
                                    <or>
                                        <contains text="@Entity"/>
                                        <contains text="@javax.persistence.Entity"/>
                                    </or>
                                </fileset>

                                <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.tmpl.xml"
                                      tofile="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"
                                      overwrite="true"/>

                                <pathconvert targetos="unix" pathsep="&quot;/&gt;&#10;        &lt;mapping class=&quot;"
                                             property="mappedClasses"
                                             refid="dataClasses">
                                    <chainedmapper>
                                        <globmapper
                                                from="${basedir}${file.separator}src${file.separator}main${file.separator}java${file.separator}"
                                                to=""/>
                                        <packagemapper from="*.java" to=""/>
                                    </chainedmapper>
                                </pathconvert>

                                <echo message="mapped classes:  ${mappedClasses}"/>

                                <replace file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"
                                         token="INSERT HBM FILES HERE"
                                         value="${mappedClasses}"/>

                                <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml"
                                      tofile="${basedir}/target/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml" overwrite="true"/>

                                <java
                                        jvm="${java.home}"
                                        classpath="${compile_classpath}"
                                        classname="net.core.jpa.hibernate.HibernateUtils">
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.sql"/>
                                </java>

                                <copy file="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.sql"
                                      tofile="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.sql.ori"
                                      overwrite="true"/>

                                <java
                                        jvm="${java.home}"
                                        classpath="${runtime_classpath}"
                                        classname="net.core.jpa.hibernate.SqlFixer">
                                    <arg value="${basedir}/src/main/resources/hibernate/hibernate.sql"/>
                                </java>

                                <!--
                                <taskdef name="instrument"
                                         classname="org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask">
                                    <classpath>
                                        <path refid="maven.runtime.classpath"/>
                                        <path refid="maven.plugin.classpath"/>
                                    </classpath>
                                </taskdef>
                                <instrument verbose="false">
                                    <fileset dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
                                        <include name="**/data/**/*.class"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </instrument>
                                -->

                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1-beta-1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Tomcat log:

```
    1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:core' did not find a matching property.
1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;.;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Solution\;C:\Program Files\Nokia\Carbide.c++ v1.3\x86Build\Symbian_Tools\Command_Line_Tools;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Symbian\Tools;C:\Program Files\CSL Arm Toolchain\bin;C:\Perl\bin\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\;c:\Program Files\Hewlett-Packard\IAM\bin;c:\Python26;c:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Sun\SDK\bin;;
1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol init
INFO: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 390 ms
1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService start
INFO: Starting service Catalina
1.3.2010 13:29:16 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine start
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/6.0.20
1.3.2010 13:29:17 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'core.root' = [C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\core\]
1.3.2010 13:29:17 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [file:C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/conf/livecliq-log4j.properties]
1.3.2010 13:29:17 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
1.3.2010 13:29:27 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
1.3.2010 13:29:27 org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
1.3.2010 13:29:27 org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/16  config=null
1.3.2010 13:29:27 org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10983 ms
1.3.2010 13:29:37 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
INFO:     Additional JARs have been added : 'xalan-2.7.0.jar'
1.3.2010 13:29:37 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading this Context has started
1.3.2010 13:29:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
1.3.2010 13:29:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
1.3.2010 13:29:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'core.root' = [C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\core\]
1.3.2010 13:29:38 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [file:C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/conf/livecliq-log4j.properties]
1.3.2010 13:29:39 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
1.3.2010 13:29:59 org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader modified
INFO:     Additional JARs have been added : 'xalan-2.7.0.jar'
1.3.2010 13:29:59 org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext reload
INFO: Reloading this Context has started
1.3.2010 13:29:59 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
1.3.2010 13:29:59 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
1.3.2010 13:30:00 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'core.root' = [C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\core\]
1.3.2010 13:30:00 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [file:C:\Work\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0/conf/log4j.properties]
1.3.2010 13:30:00 org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: Can you join the log message with the surrounding entries? Also, does this happen with a vanilla Tomcat or with JBoss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More an hint than an answer but similar Eclipse/Tomcat/Spring problems (with other JARs) are reported in [Application Context Keeps Reloading](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?p=284351) and [Tomcat behaving Strangely](http://72.5.124.102/thread.jspa?messageID=10096875). Check if your xalan JAR is not corrupted (try to open it with winzip) and redownload it if required. If not, maybe try to deploy on JBoss to see if this issue is related to the Tomcat plugin.

Comment: I will checked it as answered, because it lead me to the error. The file was corrupted yes, but the file in Eclipse's servers directory!!! In here: "C:\Work\metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\core\WEB-INF\lib". I don't know why Eclipse did not took it from Maven or Apache's directory...